# Why won't mosquitto_sub display my message from mosquitto_pub?

Tags: localhost, mqtt, message, subscription, mosquitto

I'm trying to send out a message from mosquitto_pub to mosquitto_sub on the same computer (localhost)

[image: Screenshot]

The connection seems to be stable, nothing showed up on the debug mode. I've also tried changing both host addresses to "localhost" and changing the QoS of the message to 0, 1, and 2. I am not sure what I am missing out.

Comment: First off, Cut and paste your screenshots....no one that cares about security of their system will click on your link.  Secondly, what does your Broker log say? Is there a connection from your Subscriber? Do you see the message being Published?

Comment: And how is your broker configured?

Comment: Edit the question to show the broker config and it's log output (post the text not images) when you try and publish messages